# More than one HttpPost Method in one Controller not working in Web Api

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web Api Project, First i have created a controller with one HttpPost Method then its working fine. But when i have added another HttpPost method no one is working, but when i remove any one another is working. My code is.

Web Api Controller:

```
 public class ForumPost
    {
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }
        public int CourseId { get; set; }
        public int SubjectId { get; set; }
        public int TopicId { get; set; }
        public int ContentId { get; set; }
        public string Heading { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }          
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("AddForumPost")]
    public string AddForumPost([FromBody]ForumPost _ForumPost)
    {
        string strResult = "N";
        using (ICA.LMS.Service.Models.Entities db = new Entities())
        {

        }
        return strResult;
    }

    public class Comment
    {
        public int ForumId {get;set;}
        public string Response { get; set; }
        public int ParentId { get; set; }
        public int LevelId { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("AddComment")]
    public string AddComment([FromBody]Comment cmt)
    {
        string strResult = "N";
        using (ICA.LMS.Service.Models.Entities db = new Entities())
        {

        }
        return strResult;
    }
```

Jquery Calling:

```
var comment = { ForumId: fId, Response: res, ParentId: pId, LevelId: lId, CreatedBy: uId };

jQuery.support.cors = true;
$.ajax({        
    url: 'http://localhost:1900/api/ForumApi',
    type: 'Post',
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    data:comment,
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        var efId = $('#EncForumId').val();
        if (data == "Y")
            location.replace('../Forum/ForumDiscussion?id=' + efId);
        else
            myAlert('Unable to Post. Try again!');
    },
    error: function (e) {
        myAlert(JSON.stringify(e));
    }
});
```

Error:-

```
**{"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'http://localhost:1900/api/ForumApi'."}**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by default the web api route is this

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

as you will notice there is no action in the route. 
The web api selects the action based on the HTTP Verb and the action name. You Either keep the action name `POST` or use annotation `HttpPost` or keep an action name that starts with POST (`PostComment`)

to overcome this problem and if you have to route by the action name you ust add a new route like this

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ActionApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

now any request matching this pattern of `api/{controller}/{action}/{id}` will be caught by this route and will be passed on to the respective action.

You can read more about this [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api)
 Also you will have to change now the urls you are calling so that they match the newly added route
from `http://localhost:1900/api/ForumApi` to `http://localhost:1900/api/ForumApi/AddForumPost` and like wise for the other urls

Comment: where do i add this in RouteConfig or WebApiConfig.

Comment: WebApiConfig. Before the default route